# An integral involves Gamma function

Tags: integration, exponential-function, gamma-function

Thanks for your attention, I meet an integral involves Gamma function and exponential function as follows:$$\int_a^\infty  {{x^\alpha }} {e^{cx}}\Gamma \left( {s,bx} \right)dx$$
where $a > 0,s \leqslant 0,b \geqslant 0$ and $\alpha $ is integer, here is the definition of the Gamma function:$$\Gamma \left( {\alpha ,z} \right) = \int_z^\infty  {{t^{\alpha  - 1}}{e^{ - t}}dt} $$,I have no idea about how to solve this.

Comment: More likely there is no closed form for this integral.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so, can i get a series-form result?

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of integration?

Comment: Good idea, thank you very much, i'll try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, switching the order of integration will lead to an integral on similar form than the original one.

Comment: Really? What a pity, but thanks for your help too.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is probably no closed form, a series expension is (subject to convergence conditions) :
$$I=\int_a^\infty  {{x^\alpha }} {e^{cx}}\Gamma \left( {s,bx} \right)dx$$
$$\Gamma \left( {s,bx} \right)=\Gamma(s)- \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k b^{s+k} x^{s+k}}{(s+k) k!}$$
Supposing $c<0$ among the conditions for convergence :
$$I=\Gamma(s) \int_a^\infty  x^\alpha  e^{cx} dx- \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k b^{s+k} }{(s+k) k!} \int_a^\infty x^{s+k+\alpha} e^{cx} dx$$
$$I=\Gamma(s) (-c)^{-\alpha-1} \Gamma\big(\alpha+1,(-c)a\big) - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k b^{s+k} }{(s+k) k! (-c)^{\alpha+1+s+k} }  \Gamma\big(\alpha+1-s-k,(-c)a\big)$$

Comment: wonderful!Although it's rather complex,i think this must be the result i need, thanks for your help!